# CodeIgniter - Store class instance in CI session

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, session, serialization

Recently, I've been wanting to implement the Facebook SDK for PHP in my CodeIgniter project.
Facebook sdk can be slooooow, that's why I want to store a class instance containing gathered fb & fb user details in the user session.

When I store the class instance, I can use it later on as long as I don't refresh or redirect.
When I do redirect, the value is unset...

I've read about using serialize and unserialize (for global PHP sessions), but it didn't help in this situation.

This is the fb class:

```
class FBClass {
    protected $FB = false;
    protected $FBUser = false;
    protected $FBUserProfile = false;
    protected $FBUserEmail = false;

    protected $loggedIn = false;

    protected $config = array(
        'appId' => '007',
        'secret' => '911',
        'cookie' => true,
        'fileUpload' => false,
        'allowSignedRequest' => false
    );

    protected $params = array(
        'client_id' => '007',
        'scope' => 'email'
    );

    function __construct() {
        if (!$this->FB) {
            $this->FB = new Facebook($this->config);
        }
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->loggedIn;
    }

    public function getLoginUrl() {
        $this->FB->getLoginUrl($this->params); 
    }

    public function getUser() {
        if (!$this->FBUser) {
            $this->FBUser = $this->FB->getUser();
        }
        return $this->FBUser;
    }

    public function getUserProfile() {
        if (!$this->FBUserProfile) {
            $this->FBUserProfile = $this->FB->api('/me','GET');
        }
        if ($this->FBUserProfile && !$this->FBUserEmail) {
            $emailArray = $this->FB->api('/me?fields=email');
            $this->FBUserEmail = array_key_exists('email', $emailArray) ? $emailArray['email'] : 'Onbekend';
            $this->loggedIn = true;
        }
        return $this->FBUserProfile;
    }

    public function getUserFullName() {
        return $this->FBUserProfile['name'];
    }

    public function getUserAlias() {
        return $this->FBUserProfile['username'];
    }

    public function getUserEmail() {
        return $this->FBUserEmail;
    }

    public function getUserFirstName() {
        return $this->FBUserProfile['first_name'];
    }

    public function getUserLastName() {
        return $this->FBUserProfile['last_name'];
    }

    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->FBUserProfile['id'];
    }
}
```

In my controller, I store or retrieve my FBClass instance like this:

```
public function checkFacebookState() {
    if (!$this->session->userdata('fb')) {
        $fbSes = new FBClass();
        $this->session->set_userdata('fb', serialize($fbSes));
    } else {
        $fbSes = unserialize($this->session->userdata('fb'));
    }
}
```

Storing strings in the session does work.
I know PHP is not OO, that's why I'm looking for an easy alternative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to save your instance in a session, there is no problem whether you serialize it first or not.
Take the following example for instance.
create a library test in your application/library folder:

```
class Test {
    public $testProp;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->testProp = 'testing'; 
    }
}
```

then in your controller write the following:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->library('test');
            $this->session->set_userdata('someIns',  $this->test);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

and lastly in your view:

```
<div id="container">
    <?php 
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($x = $this->session->userdata('someIns'));
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $x->testProp;
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
        echo '</pre>';
        ?>
</div>
```

the output would be:

```
object(Test)#15 (1) {
  ["testProp"]=>
  string(7) "testing"
}
testing
array(6) {
  //some session data
  ["user_data"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["someIns"]=>
  object(Test)#15 (1) {
    ["testProp"]=>
    string(7) "testing"
  }
}
```

if you noticed I used `echo $x->testProp` directly after fetching it from the session.
No serialization needed here.

With serialization:

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {   
    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->library('test');
            $this->session->set_userdata('someIns', serialize($this->test));
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

View:

```
    <div id="container">
        <?php 
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($x = $this->session->userdata('someIns'));
            echo '</pre>';
            echo '<pre>';
            $y = unserialize($x);
            echo $y->testProp;
            echo '</pre>';
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
            echo '</pre>';
            ?>
    </div>
```

Results:

```
string(44) "O:4:"Test":1:{s:8:"testProp";s:7:"testing";}"
testing
array(6) {
  //some session data
  ["user_data"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["someIns"]=>
  string(44) "O:4:"Test":1:{s:8:"testProp";s:7:"testing";}"
}
```

the word `testing` is still being echoed out.

Now your problem, apparently, is that you are getting your FB class in a wrong way,
it is a library. Thus, you need to load your library first, as I did in the above example,

```
$this->load->library('test');
$this->session->set_userdata('someIns',  $this->test);
```

or after serializing it. `$this->test` here is an instance of the `Test` class in the library folder.